# How to add a Gantt Chart in Visual Studio C# Website

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am new to programming and so. I am trying to create a website which will include image galleries, tables, charts and gantt view.

I am trying to create a gannt chart on webpage using Visual Studio and Telerik ASP.NET AJAX.

Was able to rectify the previous error and now stuck at new error:

OK Guys i was able to use the data input method for GanttView but now I am trying to implement xml import and getting this error..

```
Exception Details: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: node

Source Error: 



Line 17: 
Line 18: 
Line 19:         RadGantt1.Provider = new XmlGanttProvider(Server.MapPath("App_Code/MP.xml"));
Line 20:     }
Line 21: }


 Source File:  c:\Users\Suhaib\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\WebSites\TelerikWebSite2\Default.aspx.cs    Line:  19
```

This is codebehind

```
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using Telerik.Web.UI;

public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        RadGantt1.Provider = new XmlGanttProvider(Server.MapPath("App_Code/MP.xml"));
    }
}
```

And this is aspx page

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <telerik:RadStyleSheetManager id="RadStyleSheetManager1" runat="server" />
    </head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <telerik:RadScriptManager ID="RadScriptManager1" runat="server">
        <Scripts>
            <asp:ScriptReference Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Name="Telerik.Web.UI.Common.Core.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Name="Telerik.Web.UI.Common.jQuery.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Name="Telerik.Web.UI.Common.jQueryInclude.js" />
        </Scripts>
    </telerik:RadScriptManager>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //Put your JavaScript code here.
    </script>
    <telerik:RadAjaxManager ID="RadAjaxManager1" runat="server">
    </telerik:RadAjaxManager>
    <div>
     <telerik:RadGantt runat="server" ID="RadGantt1" SelectedView="MonthView"></telerik:RadGantt>

    </div>


         </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Some help please...

Comment: welcome to stack overflow! please post all the relevant code, to make it easier to understand what you are talking about.

Comment: I have absolutely no clue how to work in Visual Studio and .Net.. can i find a walkthrough somewhere... I have created some websites in wordpress though..

Comment: I am trying to create this   http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/gantt/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx can someone help to achieve it

Comment: Those kind of questions are off topic on stack overflow. There are plenty of free tutorials out there, and you could take a course in .NET if it really interests you. Stack overflow is a place to ask specific programming related questions that directly involve a programming language.

Comment: i have been searching over net and reading for past 5 days regarding this.. but couldnt find any solution.. i am stuck at What is iDataSource and how to create one??? any help in this regard will be much appreciated... thanks

Comment: As i wrote earlier, please post the relevant code. Show us what you have tried so far so we can try to help you.

Comment: What does the database tables etc look like?

Answer (score 0):

The error is giving you the required information (A control with ID 'Database' could not be found)

The below markup is where it is set.

```
  <telerik:RadGantt runat="server" 
ID="RadGantt1" Datasourceid="Database" Height="600px" ListWidth="350px"
                SelectedView="WeekView" Skin="Silk" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
```

With a bit of googling I came across these forums (both in the top 5 results):

[ASP.Net Forum](http://forums.asp.net/t/1134728.aspx?The+DataSourceID+of+GridView1+must+be+the+ID+of+a+control+of+type+IDataSource+A+control+with+ID+AccessDataSource+could+not+be+found+)

[ASP Forum](http://aspforums.net/Threads/149227/The-DataSourceID-of-Repeater1-must-be-the-ID-of-a-control-of-type-IDataSource-A-control-with-ID-AccessDataSource3-could-not-be-found/)

Have a look at them, they will provide you with enough information to solve your dilemma.

Comment: OK Guys i was able to use the data input method for GanttView but now I am trying to implement xml import and getting this error..                                                 Exception Details: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: node

Source Error: 



Line 17: 
Line 18: 
Line 19:         RadGantt1.Provider = new XmlGanttProvider(Server.MapPath("App_Code/MP.xml"));
Line 20:     }
Line 21: }
  

 Source File:  c:\Users\Suhaib\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\WebSites\TelerikWebSite2\Default.aspx.cs    Line:  19